# Query Spring Data Rest by RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I build a Restful API Server by Spring Data Rest.
When I GET http://localhost:8080/admin/search/findByUsername?username=12345
it return

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "admin" : [ {
      "username" : "12345",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/admin/35"
        },
        "admin" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/admin/35"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/admin/search/findByUsername?username=12345"
    }
  }
}
```

It has `_embedded` and `_links`;
I want to query this API by RestTemplate, but I only think up such solution

```java
    @Data
    static class Res {
        @Data
        static class Embedded {
            @Data
            static class Admin {
                String username;
            }
            List<Admin> admin;
        }
        Embedded _embedded;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin(String username) {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        Res res = rest.getForObject(url + "admin/search/findByUsername?username=" + username, Res.class);
        return !res.get_embedded().getAdmin().isEmpty();
    }
```

I don't think it is a good idea.
So have some elegant way to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: how about your end point return an HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND if user is not found ?

Comment: Hi @YaoUan , is there a possiblity of using Jackson? then will propose a solution.